# Uploadify will not work in ssl

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, uploadify

I am using a coldfusion upload page to upload pictures to a server. I cannot put the script in the root of the ssl path. The uploader finishes with no error, but the upload script is not being called. (I have an email sent as soon as page loads) Works only in ie8.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fileInput').uploadify({
'uploader'        : 'uploadify.swf',
'script'          : 'upload.cfm?id=<cfoutput>#NewId#</cfoutput>',
'cancelImg'       : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
'auto'            :  true,
'sizeLimit'       : '2097152',
'fileExt'         : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.docx;*.doc;*.xlsx;*.xls;*.pdf',
'fileDesc'        : 'Image Files',
'multi'           : true,
'removeCompleted' : false,
'onComplete'      :     
  function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {  
      if(response == "hello") {    
       $('#mydiv').html("hello"); }   
       }                    });
                    });
</script>

UPLOAD
<!--- -------------------------------------------->
<cfset dest_dir = "c:\test\">

<cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="Filedata" destination="#dest_dir#"  result="fileRes" nameconflict="MAKEUNIQUE">

<cfoutput>hello</cfoutput>
```

Comment: <cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="Filedata" destination="#dest_dir#"  result="fileRes" nameconflict="MAKEUNIQUE">

Answer (score 0):

I have done this also in coldfusion - my uploadify.cfm has within the CFFILE tag a result="result" and I output the file name from the finished upload:

```
<CFOUTPUT>#result.serverfilename#</CFOUTPUT>
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is only working in IE. I have a trusted certificate. It seems to only work in Firefox if it is in the root of website. It cannot be in the root of the website though.